# Can not build with release mode because of Access to the path error in VS2017

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, nuget, xamarin.uwp

When I am try to build my xamarin uwp project just in release mode i get the error in below;

**

> 2>"C:\Projects\etimkcp\MKCP\MKCP\MKCP.UWP\MKCP.UWP.csproj" (Rebuild
>   target) (1) -> 2>(ComputeNativePackageInputsAndOutputs target) ->  2> 
>   C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018: The "ComputeManagedBinaries" task failed unexpectedly.
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.15063.0\Windows.winmd' is denied.
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
>   String maybeFullPath)
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
>   secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
>   Boolean checkHost)
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Cci.MemoryMappedFile.OpenFileMemoryMap(String filename,
>   Byte*& buffer, UInt32& length)
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Cci.MemoryMappedFile.CreateMemoryMappedFile(String
>   localFileName, IBinaryDocument binaryDocument)
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Cci.MetadataReaderHost.OpenBinaryDocument(IBinaryDocument
>   sourceDocument)
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Cci.PeReader.OpenModule(IBinaryDocument
>   binaryDocument, ModuleIdentity& moduleIdentity)
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Cci.PeReader.DefaultHost.LoadUnitFrom(String location)
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at ilc.ComputeManagedBinaries.Execute()
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   2>C:\Users\Özge.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(535,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

**

thanks for any idea about this problem.

Comment: `Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.15063.0\Windows.winmd' is denied.` Seems to be the key issue

Comment: Have you tried to run VS2017 as asministrator? You could try clean your solution then rebuild it.

Comment: thanks Nico, when i did what you say the problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.15063.0\Windows.winmd' is denied.

You could run VS2017 with `Administrator` clean your solution then rebuild it.